# How do I backgroundReload in multiple stages in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, datastore

I'm fetching a list of records, say `posts`, without relationships. When I pick a single post, I would like to see the post immediately, and background-load its relationships.

This is possible like so:

```
this.store.findRecord('posts', params.id, {
    reload: false,
    backgroundReload: true,
```

Once the relationships are loaded, the view is automatically updated.

However, some relationships are complex and take some time to load. They become relevant after scrolling. There is one `hasMany` relationship that *is* important for the initial pageview. And their relationships are also important, but I prefer to defer them too.

So, is it possible to do the following points in order when clicking on a single post?

- Open post directly from cache (`reload: false`)
- Background-reload including one relationship *excluding* the relationship's relationships

  - Background-reload relationship *including* relationship's relationships
- Background-reload including all relationships

E.g. after the initial template is drawn using the cached model, 3 more updates will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reload()` method that is available on [`DS.Model`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Model) and [`DS.ManyArray`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.ManyArray). It returns a Promise that settles after the record has been reloaded. You could use that Promise to chain your reloading as needed.

You should guard against reloading a not yet loaded record by using `isLoaded` property available on `DS.Model` as well as on `DS.ManyArray`.

You could use the [`eachRelationship` method](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Model/methods/eachRelationship?anchor=eachRelationship) of `DS.Model` to iterate over all relationships.